# Javascript expanding ribbon for links

Tags: javascript, slide, ribbon, expand

I'm looking to get a ribbon like thing to expand on my site. It has to be in the middle of the page, not at the side of the screen. So it should be a tiny piece of the ribbon with the word more on it and then it would slide itself open on click.  This is where the problem comes in. I found this http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/10/ and it does what I want but only at the side. I would also like it to change text on click from more to facebook, twitter etc links.

Help is much appreciated.

fiddle code below because i can't post the link without it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var r=0, dir=true;
$(".slide").click(function() {
    dir = !dir;
    r = dir? -280 : 0;
    $(this).stop().animate({left: r+'px'}, 800);
});
```

});

// http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp